# Why does nothing happen when I press submit on my ASP.NET registration form?

Tags: asp.net

I have a registration form that is connected to a database table that uses RequiredFieldValidators, RegularExpressionValidators, and PasswordStrength. When I press submit, nothing happens. Any clue why this is happening? Please can you help. Thank you.

```
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div style="margin-left:30%;margin-top:40px;">
    <asp:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="MainPanel" BorderColor="blue" Radius="6" Corners="All"></asp:RoundedCornersExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="MainPanel" BackColor="Transparent" runat="server" BorderWidth="5" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="blue" Width="525" Height="475">
        <div style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px">
        <h2 style="color:Blue;text-align:center">Registration</h2>
        <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="150"><asp:Label ID="lblFirstname" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Text="First name:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td width="350"><asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstname" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstname" ErrorMessage="First name is required." ToolTip="First name is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="150"><asp:Label ID="lblMiddlename" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Text="Middle name:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td width="350"><asp:TextBox ID="txtMiddlename" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMiddlename" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMiddlename" ErrorMessage="Middle name is required." ToolTip="Middle name is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="150"><asp:Label ID="lblLastname" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Text="Last name:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td width="350"><asp:TextBox ID="txtLastname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLastname" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastname" ErrorMessage="Last name is required." ToolTip="Last name is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td width="150"></td>
          <td width="350" class="smtxt">Tip: Make sure the names match the traveler's passport or driver's license to avoid travel delays.</td></tr>
        </table>        
        <hr align="left" width="500" />
        <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <td width="150"><asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Text="Username:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td width="350"><asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUsername" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" ErrorMessage="Username is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="150"><asp:Label ID="lblEmailAddress" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Text="Email address:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td width="350"><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" Text="You must enter an email address" ErrorMessage="You must enter an email address" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddr" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
        </tr>
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably failing one of the validators requirements and just not displaying the error message.  I would look at your validators and make sure that they are not suppressing error messages or you're passing those messages to a summary control

Comment: can you edit your question and post the code of the aspx page?

Comment: I think it's your password strength validator.  take that out and see if it works

Comment: It seems like it's stuck. If I take out all the validators, it works, but if I leave them in, I'm stuck on the page.

Comment: take out the validators one at a time until you find the issue.

Comment: It was the first RegularExpressionValidator that was the problem. Thanks for your advice.